Why redux losing it new value when pushing a new value into the redux array and refreshing even though redux-persist is there?
I am using redux for state management in my app.
const addStepReducer = (
  stepDetails = [
    {
      stepId: "001",
      stepTitle: "Step Name",
      stepDescription:"Step Desc",
    },
  ],
  action
) => {
   if (action.type === "ADD_STEP") {
    stepDetails.push(action.payload);
    
  }
  

  return stepDetails;
};

The above code is my reducer function.
But when I reload the page the stepDetails will be populated with the default value only, the new value pushed will be gone. But other redux stores persists its value after reloading.
I don't understand why redux is behaving in this way. But I know one thing instead of pushing if we used assigning a value it will persist i.e. stepDetails=action.payload;(This is possible if we need just the payload only but in my case i need the array itself). Please let me know if anyone knows about this issue.

return [...stepDetails];

stepDetails.push(action.payload); is a mutation... what sort of reducer function are you using? Use a mutable state update. What state/store persistence are you using? Please [edit] to clarify the specific problem you would like help with and include a complete [mcve].

You cannot use mutating logic like that if you decide to write Redux in the pre-2019 legacy style like you are doing.
Generally, the recommendation would be that you follow the official tutorial and learn modern Redux.
In modern Redux, your code would look like this and you would be allowed to use .push
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
const stepSlice = createSlice({
  name: "stepDetails",
  initialState: [
    {
      stepId: "001",
      stepTitle: "Step Name",
      stepDescription:"Step Desc",
    },
  ],
  reducers: {
    addStep(state, action) {
      state.push(action.payload)
    }
  }
})
export const { addStep } = stepSlice.actions
const addStepReducer = stepSlice.reducer

In the legacy Redux reducer you are writing here, you're not allowed to write mutable functions like .push and instead of
stepDetails.push(action.payload);

you'd have to do
return [...stepDetails, action.payload]

instead.
